# XMPP League of Legends Python

Tags: python, xmpp, chat

I am trying to create a bot that reads a message in a file and then send it to a recipient in League of Legends.

I am using xmpppy library. If you have a better and easier one you can tell me :)

This is my code:

```
from xmpp import *

username = 'MY_LOGIN_ID'
passwd = 'MY_LOGIN_PASSWORD'

conn = Client("pvp.net")

if not conn.connect(server=("chat.euw1.lol.riotgames.com", 5223)):
    print "Connection failed."
    exit()
if not conn.auth(username, "AIR_" + passwd, "xiff"):
    print "auth failed."
    exit()

conn.sendInitPresence()

roster = None

def message_handler(conn, msg):

    user = "Rekkles"

    LF = open('last.txt', 'r')
    text = LF.readline()

    txt = "%s : this is the text in the note." % (text)  

    alert = Message(user, txt)
    alert.setType("chat")
    conn.send(alert)

conn.RegisterHandler("message", message_handler)

conn.sendInitPresence(requestRoster=1)

roster = conn.getRoster()

while conn.isConnected():
    try:
        conn.Process(10)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

But this is not working. How can I solve this?

I am also doubtful about the recipient, is writing only "Rekkles" okay or I have to write its full address like "sumXXXXXXXX@pvp.net", if I have to use this, how can I convert "Rekkles" to "sumXXXXXXXX@pvp.net"?

Thanks for reading.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I like how straightforward this post is - but why would anybody help you create a chat bot?

Comment: Well, I just needed some help and I felt like asking here :) but I managed to solve by myself :)

Comment: That's awesome xd - but srsly those bots are annoying af.

Comment: Post it as an answer to your own question then! I'm curious! @SpeedyBoosting